# Drop shadows for IE10+? DX filters are no longer supported

Tags: html, css, drop-shadow

The problem with box-shadows is that it does not support PNG transparency unlike drop-shadows. So i want to use drop-shadows over box-shadows, is there some other way so that i can see the effect of drop-shadows in IE10+ as well.

```css
img {
  filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px black)
}
```

```html
<img src="https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/favicon-196.223e1bcaf067.png">
```

The above snippet is not working for IE10+.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may its will help you

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```